# java cast LinkedHashMap to class extending LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, casting, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a class (EntireFile) that extends the LinkedHashMap. I try to cast:

```
EntireFile old = (EntireFile) functionReturningLinkedHashMap();
```

It throws exception with message: "java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.gmail.maximsmol.YAML.GroupMap".

```
public class EntireFile extends LinkedHashMap<String, GroupMap>

public class GroupMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, CategoryMap>

public class CategoryMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>
```

Please help me to solve the error!

Comment: You are trying to downcast your LinkedHashMap to an EntireFile. If the cast does not work, that's because the runtime type of the object returned by your method is not an EntireFile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the reference returned simply *isn't* a reference to an instance of `EntireFile`. If `functionReturningLinkedHashMap` just returns a `LinkedHashMap`, it can't be cast to an `EntireFile`, because it *isn't* one - how would it get any extra information about it?

(Judging by your exception, you're actually talking about `GroupMap` rather than `EntireFile`, but the same thing applies.)

There's nothing special about `LinkedHashMap` here - the same is *always* true in Java:

```
Object foo = new Object();
String bar = (String) foo; // Bang! Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting you can copy the data to the type of map you need.

```
EntireFile old = new EntireFile(functionReturningLinkedHashMap());
```

or

```
EntireFile old = new EntireFile();
old.putAll(functionReturningLinkedHashMap());
```